# Getting SharePoint crawl history

Tags: sharepoint, web-crawler

I have an application that uses the Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.CrawlHistory class to read crawl history information once a day and save it to a database where we can generate reports and statistics.  For some reason, though, this class will not return data for crawls that started on the current date; it will only return data for crawls that started on an earlier data.  Can anyone explain how to get this class to return data for all crawls that have run?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to see the source code of the `CrawlHistory` class (additionally, you may want to use the [FileGenerator](http://www.jasonbock.net/jb/codefilegenerator.aspx) add-in).
2. Check the `dbo.proc_MSS_GetCrawlHistory` stored procedure from the `SharedServicesInstanceName_Search_DB` database (all `GetCrawlHistory` overloads use it internally).